# Database and program organization in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, relational

First let me give you some context.

I've some data that looks like this:

- Runner1 | Date1 | Time1 | Laps1 | Time2 | Laps2 | ... | Time50 | Laps50
- Runner1 | Date2 | Time1 | Laps1 | Time2 | Laps2
- Runner1 | Date3 | Time1 | Laps1 | ...   | Time32 | Laps 32

Meaning: the runner has a different number of total time and laps for each date.

Here's a mockup of how I've created my SQL database:

(sorry for the ASCII art but it's my first question)

```
|Runner  |     |RunnerTimes   |    |Time    |
|RunnerID|-----|RunnerTimesID |----|TimeID  |
               |RunnerID      |    |Laps    |
               |TimeID        |    |Duration|
               |Date          |
```

My problem is that I have some code that was created before the database:

```
public class iRunner
{
    public int[] laps;
    public TimeSpan[] duration;
}
public static class RunnerFunctions
{
    public static double AverageLaps(iRunner runner)
    {
        return runner.laps.Average();
    }
}
```

So I can get all my runner data using:

```
Runner runner = dbContext.Runner.Where(item=>item.RunnerID == 1);
```

Then I have to "convert" to the class format:

```
iRunner r = new iRunner();
r.Laps =  runner.RunnerTimes.Select(a=>a.Laps).toArray();
r.Duration = runner.RunnerTimes.Select(a=>a.Duration).toArray();
```

And then I can actually call the methods that are pre-existing:

```
Double average = RunnerFunctions.Average(runner);
```

Now that you have the background, here are my questions:

1. Is that the right way to model my data in SQL?
2. Is there a better way to "convert" my SQL structure into my existing classes and functions?

Some extra data:

1. The structure I've shown above is fake but resembles my actual structure
2. I'm converting 3 thousand entries in one table, it's taking 500 ms to retrieve all the data from the database, but taking about 4 minutes to convert into the existing class structure.

Thank you!

Comment: You said that the code was created before the database - do you mean that you're not able to refactor or change the code? Also, are you tied to using Entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

If the code exists first you might consider using Code First approach with Entity Framework.

[Entity Framework Code First: Let's Try It](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318010/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Let-s-Try-It)

Comment: Hi Saleh, the problem with that approach that we found is that the structures in the classes do not work with code first, for instance, how can we use a property that is an array of integers? such as the laps property int[] Laps? Thank you for your answer anyhow.

Comment: You can use one table for Runners and one table for Laps for example and a third table for mapping from the runner to the laps. The mapping table will have RunnerID and LapID so you will have One to Many cardinality. In the same way you will have mapping from runners to Durations.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema design is close to what I'd use:

```
Runner 
========
id  -- autoincrement

Run
==========
runnerId  -- fk to Runner.id
startedAt  -- timestamp
laps  -- int count
duration  -- int duration in milliseconds/seconds 
          -- (unless your RDBMS has a 'duration' type).
```

`RunnerTimes` doesn't appear to be all that useful at the moment, unless you end up providing us with more 'real world' info.
Especially with the number of runs so variable, this is what I'd recommend.

Personally, I find the pre-existing code a little suspect (Does it really have public data members like that?).  Also, why can't you do the average database-side (either directly, or if Linq-to-SQL supports it, that way)?  And both the 500ms for the retrieve and 4 minutes for the convert sound ridiculously long; how many rows are there per runner?  Do you have the necessary indices?  And don't know enough about the relevant frameworks, but I suspect that `runner.RunnerTimes.Select(...)` is doing more work than it should.